# The type or namespace 'name' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference, visual-studio-2015, using-statement

I am trying to build the solution 'NopCommerce'(solution name) of my project..
But it shows the following type of errors:

**The type or namespace name 'UasParser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I know this question has been asked quiet a few times and most of the times i came across a solution which says that it is the client profiling issue and

**set ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".Net Framework 4"**

this would solve my problem and give me a successful build.
But the thing is i am new to .Net and I don't know from where i can do that. Please tell me the steps to change the client profile.
Thanks a lot in advance.. :)

Comment: which Version of the NopCommerce do you have? As far as I know, NC doesnt have client profile in any of it is projects by default.